# How much do Dragon’s propellant tanks weigh?

Tags: dragon

I’m trying to figure out how much dragon xl might weigh, and I would like to approximate how much tank weight gets added per kilogram of extra propellant.

I asked [About how much do hydrazine/N2O4 tanks weigh per kilogram of propellant](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/44077/about-how-much-do-hydrazine-n2o4-tanks-weigh-per-kilogram-of-propellant) and was advised to make a more specific question